# Why ACTION_DOWN may occasionally not get triggered for ListView in android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to do some work in `onTouch()` method of my `ListView`. The problem is that sometimes I receive `ACTION_UP` type of `MotionEvent` without previously receiving `ACTION_DOWN`, which completelly ruins my app. Could somebody explain what might be a problem?

Here's some code of my `OnTouchListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("TAG", "ATCION_DOWN");        
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Log.d("TAG", "ACTION_MOVE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("TAG", "ACTION_UP");
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's what I get from logs:

- 09-16 20:15:02.116 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ATCION_DOWN
  09-16 20:15:02.186 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:02.846 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ATCION_DOWN
  09-16 20:15:02.916 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:03.586 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:04.166 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ATCION_DOWN
  09-16 20:15:04.276 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:05.316 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:06.086 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:07.046 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:08.136 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ATCION_DOWN
  09-16 20:15:08.256 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP
  09-16 20:15:09.206 25661-25661/com.ulmaxy.morny D/TAG: ACTION_UP

Comment: Are you overriding some other `View`'s `onTouchEvent()`. If you are make sure you are returning correctly (either `true` or `false`).

Comment: @Abbas I don't do that, but I have another Views inside of `ListView`'s item that have their `onClickListener`. Although I'm sure that when ACTION_DOWN doesn't show up I'm not clicking those views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your ListView inside a ScrollView? if it it, sometimes the ScrollView can "steal" the Action_DOWN.
EDIT: accidentally called ScrollView SpinnerView at first, my bad.

EDIT2: The problem was apparently that the child views were "stealing" the event (since the event is passed to the child lowest in the layout hierarchy). You can solve that by returning false on their OnTouchEvents.

Comment: No, `ListView` is inside of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Have you tried returning true instead of false? Sorry I had to post this as an answer, I cannot comment posts that aren't mine yet. @ulmaxy

Comment: Well, if I return true then the event is considered to be handled by `OnTouch()`, therefore I need to implement all the logic inside of this method, such things as vertical scrolling, etc, which I clearly don't want to do.

Comment: Returning false from an ACTION_DOWN means you do not want the event and other views will have the opportunity to handle it. If it doesn't have any overlapping views, then the parent will handle it. @ulmaxy

Comment: That's true, but somehow I can receive `ACTION_UP` even after I returned false after handling `ACTION_DOWN`, which is quite confusing. Anyway, I just tried to return true from `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_MOVE`, but I still have my problem @OliveraP

Comment: I just saw that you have children views in your ListView and that they have their own listeners.  A clickEvent will be delivered to the lowest child element in the layout hierarchy. If this element does not have an onClick behaviour it will pass the event up to its parent until the event gets handled. Have you returned false from their onclick/ontouch listeners? If that doesn't help, remove all the children and see if the ACTION_DOWN registeres properly then, if it does, that's the issue. @ulmaxy

Comment: Unfortunatelly, onClick() doesn't return anything (void), so it's neither false nor true @OliveraP

Comment: Thank you man! I just noticed that when I touch that view that has its onClickListener and start scrolling up/down I don't receive `ACTION_DOWN` event, so that's the problem. But what can I do about that? I still need it to have its onClickListener. @OliveraP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123540/discussion-between-oliverap-and-ulmaxy).